# EclipseLink: PostgreSQL returning empty list as defualt value for text[]?

Tags: database, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, postgresql-9.1

I am using `postgresql` as my database & is using Java on the Application server (AS) side using JPA (Java persistence API) implemtation `eclipselink`.

I have certain columns using `text[]` as datatype in postgres which map to `List` in jpa object on the AS side.

**JPA**

```
    @Struct(name="label,.....")
    @Entity
    @Table(name="\"XYZ\"", schema="\"XYZ\"")
    @NamedQuery(name="XYZ.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM XYZ r")
    public class XYZ implements  Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="\"resourceID\"")
        private String resourceID;

        @Array(databaseType = "text")
        @Column(name="\"label\"")
        private List<String> label;

.........
        // getter/setters 

}
```

So here, `label` is stored as `text[]` in postgres & mapped to `List<String>` in JPA object.

When I save the JPA object with `List` value as `null`, on retrieving the JPA I get **Empty list** as the value, but never **null**.

Why does Postgres returning `empty list` as the default value even when I was saving I set it as `null`. For my use case `empty list` and `null` have different semantics.

It does not happen for `String` types, there it does not give empty string.

Is `text[]` defaults to empty list ?

I could not find any concrete info on the issue ??

**EDIT 1: **
I tried setting the field to `String[]` in JPA as below:

```
    @Struct(name="label,.....")
    @Entity
    @Table(name="\"XYZ\"", schema="\"XYZ\"")
    @NamedQuery(name="XYZ.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM XYZ r")
    public class XYZ implements  Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="\"resourceID\"")
        private String resourceID;


        @Column(name="\"label\"")
        private String[] label;

.........
        // getter/setters 

}
```

I get an exception on runtime:

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "label" is of type text[] but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 413
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:411)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(CachedPreparedStatement.java:119)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
```

**EDIT 2:**

On trying the `ListToArrayConverter` as mentioned in your answer I get an exception while persisting:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "label" is of type text[] but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: Without knowing the implementation detail returning an empty List or Array is a good practice because you cannot get a NullPointerException.. Are you using Hibernate or EclipseLink.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli : 'EclipseLink' . Yes it's a good practice. But in my use case null and empty hold different semantics. And passing it back to client an empty list, even though it didn't touch the field won't be good. Any configuration to handle it in Dao layer itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink handles the List like if it was a ToMany relationship and therfore it's always initialized with an empty List. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink

If you don't like the empty list and want null instead you could create your own converter like:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ListToArrayConveter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, Object> {

    @Override
    public PostgreSQLTextArray convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attribute) {
        if (attribute == null || attribute.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] rst = new String[attribute.size()];
        return new PostgreSQLTextArray(attribute.toArray(rst));
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(Object dbData) {
            List<String> rst = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] elements = ((String[]) dbData);
        for (String element : elements) {
            rst.add(element);
        }
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return rst;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So after doing a 'dao.retrieve', there ain't any way to know whether actually it was null or empty list ?? As eclipselink is overriding the null to empty list..

Comment: No. Due to advantages of List API it's preferred at java end! PS: it's used all over code base expecting List<String>

Comment: Sure but Can you try and see if you get an empty array or null

Comment: Ok.. Will let u know by tomorrow. Night at this side of the ocean.

Comment: I tried setting it to `String[]`, but getting an exception on runtime. Please see edits to the question for details

Comment: Please see my answer. There you see how you could create your own converter that will return null if the list is empty. But this is maybe also not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I want null returned when it's null in DB & empty list when it's an empty list in DB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177562/discussion-between-siddharth-trikha-and-simon-martinelli).

Comment: I would suggest to open an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues

Comment: Please see the second edit in my question. I tried the `Converter` mentioned in your answer